# Create a dynamic database in excel

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

**Hello everyone,**

I can't find a good solution to one excel problem, I suppose it is very easy, but somehow I can't find it.

Short explanation. I have an excel worksheet with product information. For example it will looking like this:
[example of product data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/481qW.png)

I would like to create some product worksheets with price calculation, depending on which country is dedicated for (point 8 and 9).

[example of whole excel workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADCwb.png)

**1 and 2** - here should appear data from worksheet "data", if I have "1" in suitable column:
[suitable column in worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dx32.png)

**3,4,5** - information in this column I will provide manually for each country worksheet.

**6,7** - cells with formula for calculation.

**Where is the problem?**

When I manually add some information in columns 3, 4 or 5, and then I will sort data in "data" worksheet, all calculation gone wrong. Columns 1 and 2 will change as in "data", but 3,4,5 will stay in the same cells.

**Have you got an idea how to do it?**

The necessary things:

1. product information for sheets "country 1", "country 2" should be the same as in worksheet "data", but depends on availability for product in specific country (information in column "active  country");
2. when I sort columns in worksheet "data" it will not ruin calculation in worksheets "country 1", "country 2" and information provided manually will "follow" the right product id;
3. there will be no empty fields between rows.

**Will be grateful for any ideas.**

Comment: Instead of giving us a theme, please edit your question and show us what you tried by your own.

Comment: I love Excel and I think it's a great program for worksheets, but honestly, Excel **is not** appropiate for databases, because sometimes even for easy stuff you need complicated codes, check everything, volatile functions, overcharge, and easy to break. Consider doing a serious database for this in other softwares like SQL, Access, and so on. It will be easier, and you can connect Excel to it for advanced calculations.